# Remove all elements from array where integers are lower than 3

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I need to delete all elements where `FacetValueCount` is lower than `3`.

How can I do this?

This is my array: Array name is `$farben`

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FacetValueName"]=>
    string(4) "Blau"
    ["FacetValueCount"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FacetValueName"]=>
    string(7) "Schwarz"
    ["FacetValueCount"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FacetValueName"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
    ["FacetValueCount"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["FacetValueName"]=>
    string(4) "Grau"
    ["FacetValueCount"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) might be useful here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$farben = ARRAY();
$farben[] = array('FacetValueName'=>'Blau',  'FacetValueCount' => 5);
$farben[] = array('FacetValueName'=>'Schwarz',  'FacetValueCount' => 3);
$farben[] = array('FacetValueName'=>'blue',  'FacetValueCount' => 2);
$farben[] = array('FacetValueName'=>'Grau',  'FacetValueCount' => 1);

print '<pre>'; var_dump($farben); print '</pre>';

foreach ($farben AS $key => $row) {
  if ($row['FacetValueCount'] < 3) { unset($farben[$key]); }
}

print '<pre>'; var_dump($farben); print '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: what comes into $key and row? sorry im beginner

Comment: `$key` is the index of the array, the array "keys/indexes". The `$row` contains the value(s) of the array index ... here another array `$row`. This works "automagically" when writing the `foreach` like this.

Comment: so the key is "array" ?

Comment: No, it is `[0]` in the first "loop", then `[1][2][3]`

Comment: Ok, fixed ... missing `$` in front of `row`

Answer (score -2):

try this...

```
    $farben = array_filter($farben, function($row) { 
if($row["FacetValueCount"] > 3) {
    return $row;
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you ... but LESSER THAN 3 ... `< 3`

Comment: Please do not edit this answer with changing `> 3` to `< 3`. `< 3` is wrong here, `> 3` is not ideal but it is up to author to correct it.

Comment: The second argument of `array_filter` should be a predicate that tells whether each element should be accepted (when the predicate returns *truthy*) or filtered out (when the predicate returns *falsy*), like the following: `$farben = array_filter($farben, function ($each) { return $each['FacetValueCount'] >= 3; })`